# Maven not recognize environment variables

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am running spring boot application and everything works fine in relative for database connection.

but when i am runnig maven test i get this error `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost'` .

this is my properties file

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maventest?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.main.banner-mode=off 
server.port=8081
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
```

database username and password are environment variables.

and my question is if there is a way to make maven to use those variables values.

Comment: where are you passing env variable?

Comment: I assume that you are using the Maven Properties plugin.  Correct?